# Kubuntu 20.04.1 application updates

Tags: updates, kubuntu, software-center

I installed applications such as : `Stacer`,`Latte`,`Sweeper`,`ONLYOFFICE`,`easyTAG`,`Files`,etc. through software center `Discover`. I noticed that some of them are not updated to the latest stable version.

My question is if these applications will update automatically ? (or i will have to uninstall them and install again with the latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update applications installed trough `Discover` via the GUI in the updates menu of `Discover` or with `apt` using these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

the first will only update what versions are available and the second will then download and apply those updates to all your applications.

However the version available in the official repos might not be the latest version. To get this version you should look on the official websites off each app (or their github page). There you might find instructions on how to add their repo, which will then let you update from them through `Discover` or `apt-get`

For example `Stacer` has their own repo listed on [their github page](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer#ppa-repository-for-ubuntu) under PPA Repository (for ubuntu)